# argument after ** must be a mapping, not Cursor

Tags: python, mongodb, function

I need help with this Error :

When I run my code, connecting at MongoDB and do a "Find" :

[Stricture Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPZwc.png)

The answer is :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ispdS.png)

I put a parameter when I called the def:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGU4j.png)

So that's it. I hope can you help me.

Comment: Posting code/errors as image links makes it harder for us to help.  Please post all code and errors as plain text.

Comment: A quick guide on question asking: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask